# Error code 1054 unknown column `John` in field list 1

Tags: mysql, workbench

I am trying to add the employee first name but I keep getting the error. I have tried changes based on similar issue and videos I have watched but nothing seems to get rid of the error.

```
create table `Employee Information`.`Employee`(
`EmployeeID` int not null,
`EmployeeFirstName` varchar(255) not null,
`EmployeeLastName` varchar(255) not null,
`SupervisorID` int not null,
primary key (`EmployeeID`),
foreign key (`SupervisorID`) references employee (`EmployeeID`)
on delete no action
on update no action
);

insert into `Employee` (EmployeeID, EmployeeFirstName, EmployeeLastName, SupervisorID) values (1, `John`, `Smith`, 52);
```

Any help?

Comment: create table `Employee Information`.`Employee`(
`EmployeeID` int not null,
`EmployeeFirstName` varchar(255) not null,
`EmployeeLastName` varchar(255) not null,
`SupervisorID` int not null,
primary key (`EmployeeID`),
foreign key (`SupervisorID`) references employee (`EmployeeID`)
on delete no action
on update no action);  ::::: apologies for the duplicate comment was trying to make the table a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You are using backticks (``` \``) for your values rather than regular quotes ( ```'`). The backticks are used around table names and column names. Single quotes are used for strings like the strings "John" and "Smith" in your value pair. The following SQL statement would work assuming that "52" is in fact an existing supervisor:

```
INSERT INTO `Employee`
  (`EmployeeID`, `EmployeeFirstName`, `EmployeeLastName`, `SupervisorID`)
  VALUES (1, 'John', 'Smith', 52)
```